# Should I override == for object and MyType?

Tags: c#

I have a `struct` called `MyType` that implements `IEquatable<MyType>`.

I have implemented `operator ==(MyType x, MyType y)`, but should I also implement `operator ==(MyType x, object y)` for the case below?

For example:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyType x, object y)
{
    if (y is MyType)
    {
        return x == (MyType)y;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = new MyType();
object b = new MyType();

var result = (a == b); // ?
```

Comment: Could you add an example of how a use of this operator would look like?

Comment: @HimBromBeere added

Comment: @HimBromBeere - wouldnt an `as` cast never return `null` because its a `struct`?

Comment: @Igor Ah, overread it´s a struct, yo, you´re right. But actually it won´t return null, but simply fails to compile unless `MyType` is a nullable struct.

Comment: I think it's always a good idea to override equality operator to other types than your defined type. This makes more sense when used with generics or "object based" methods.

Comment: If your type is a `struct`, how would it be boxed?

Comment: @Codor See in the usage. Whenever a struct is cast to object it is *boxed*. Most of the time this happens without user noticing it, for example when using the non-generic `ArrayList` and putting an instance of `MyType` into it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you overload `operator==` in this way, you will have a difference between that and `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other)`, so I suggest that you DON'T do this.

Comment: *Personally*, I think it would obscure the code just for the sake of hiding a cast. It would allow a lot more "wrong" code to compile since now anything can be compared to a `MyType`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Depends on how OP implements the `==`-operator for `MyType m1, MyType m2`. If that redirects to `IEquatable` everything would be fin I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CTS type does this, as far as I know. Good examples include *Decimal* and *DateTime*, which both only implement equality for their respective types and not for their base types or interfaces.

Moreover, this implementation may encourage comparing virtually any type with your struct, even other structs, and someone who might use your code in the future may think comparing *MyType* with *MyOtherType* could make sense, while all it would do is boxing the other type and then returning false. Also one usually interprets `==` on `object` as meaning reference equality.

> In addition, you should overload the **op_Equality** and **op_Inequality** operators. This ensures that all tests for equality return consistent results.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not tell which equality operators you should overload, and the second sentence may actually be interpreted in the terms of `MyType == object` being consistent with `MyType.Equals(object)`. However, the fact that no .NET types actually do this and that it leads to confusion are sufficient to say that it is not a good practice.

If other types can be treated as *MyType*, overload the explicit or implicit cast.